# Get derived Pawn from collision actor in UE4

Tags: c++, unreal

I am trying to build a basic RTS unit selection but any time I try to possess the target pawn it crashes.

The pawn in the collision is a blueprint derived directly from APawn.

**Am I casting from the actor incorrectly?**

**How do i correctly get a pointer to my target unit from a collision?**

```
void A_test_PlayerController::Input(FHitResult HitResult)
{

    // hit something
    if (HitResult.bBlockingHit)
    {
        AActor* hitActor = HitResult.GetActor();
        APawn* hitPawn = Cast<APawn>(hitActor);

        // hit a pawn
        if (hitPawn != nullptr)
        {
            // pawn is not currently controlled
            if (!hitPawn->IsControlled())
            {
                Possess(hitPawn); // <- crashes here!
                // selected new pawn
            }
            else
            {
                // pawn is already controlled
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // did not hit any pawns
        }

    }

}
```

Edit: found this, seems i might be doing it the right way, but it still crashes..
https://answers.unrealengine.com/questions/59297/line-trace-not-recognizing-actor.html